# Finding missing number from a table

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

This is a brainteaser I recently encountered:

Find the missing number in the table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
26& 6 & 5 & 4 \\ \hline
13 & 3& 2& 5\\ \hline
25 & 7 & 3& 6\\ \hline
25 & 5 & 4& x \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I want to find $x$. I've tried many things, including the following:

- Looking at the prime factors of all the numbers.
- Computing prefix sums/differences across the columns.
- Computing sums of submatrices.

However, I haven't been able to make any notable observations. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's

> 5

because

> col 1 = col 2 + col 3 x col 4